# Missing CSRF token when hitting password_reset endpoint

Tags: django, django-csrf, django-rest-framework

- The setup is django 1.10 DRF, using `url('^', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),` for authentication.
- I'm upgrading from django 1.8 to 1.10.
- The issue is that hitting the password_reset endpoint, with postman for instance, at `http://localhost:4200/v1/password_reset/` requires a CSRF token in the cookie, which I do not have.
- What am I missing? I tried comparing the `login` workflow to the `password_reset` workflow. Both views have the decorator `@csrf_protect`. But when hitting the `login` endpoint, in middleware/csrf.py, the login view has the `csrf_exempt` flag on. Furthermore, when we hit the login endpoint, the backend sends back the csrftoken data for the cookie. Nothing like that happens for password_reset.

Any ideas as to what I'm missing or how I could troubleshoot further?

Comment: do you have this `'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware'` in your settings.py ??